# How can I create a webpage where the user can enter data in form, which is then added in a new table row

Tags: php, html, forms

Using html and php, i want to create a webpage where a user can add an entry and this will then appear at the end of a html table which will increase as more entries are added, and each row keeps its css style rules. 
One section of table includes a row for date, a row for title and a row for entry, each have their own style rule. The user enters each of these in a form and a new 'section' of table is added to the existing table with 3 new rows.

How can i do this

Comment: Have you tried google searching this - I can't imagine you came up empty there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create one form and below that display table with form data.
After filling form data will be added into database using ajax jquery.

Create one php page with only table in it.

If successfully data inserted then load that new page in table div which contain only table on success of insert data ajax jquery function.